# How to generate ZAK token to Start a meeting in ZOOM

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, zoom-sdk

I am trying to integrate the latest zoom SDK iOS(5.10.1.3038) in my application, Previously I tried to login using email and password along with meeting Id to start the meeting. I know that functionality is deprecated, So I am using the OAuth authentication also I want ZAK token to host the meeting, I tried to generate the ZAK token using URLScheme (PKCE) OAuth but Its not working. Also I tried using the API also to generate the ZAK token still getting error code as 4700. I have some doubt

1. should ZAK token be generated from mobile, If so anyone can please
   guide how to generate.
2. Should I authorize each time to start a meeting, if so which account
   should be used authorize our admin account has around 100 user
   should we use those or the personal account of the clients.

I referred this to generate the ZAK through API
https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/methods/#operation/userToken

```
 //Sample for Start Param interface
MobileRTCMeetingStartParam * param = nil;

MobileRTCMeetingStartParam4WithoutLoginUser * user = 
[[MobileRTCMeetingStartParam4WithoutLoginUser alloc] init];
user.userType = MobileRTCUserType_APIUser;
user.meetingNumber = kSDKMeetNumber;
user.userName = kSDKUserName;
user.userID = kSDKUserID;
user.isAppShare = appShare;

user.zak = kZAK;
param = user;

MobileRTCMeetError ret = [ms startMeetingWithStartParam:param];
```

Answer (score 0):

Too late for responding the question, but you can fetch from the user's profile.
[Please check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwObF.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).